# Extract centroid of shape by erosion in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I developed some code to extract the centroids of a binary image with several small blobs (like blurred dots). The code is C++ and I have been using the `findContours` routine from OpenCV as follows

```
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(src, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
cv::Moments M1;
vector<cv::Point2f> dots(contours.size());
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    M1 = cv::moments(contours[i], true);
    dots[i] = cv::Point2f(float(M1.m10/M1.m00), float(M1.m01/M1.m00));
}
```

The problem is that the `findContours` cannot be synthesized into an FPGA, so I must follow a different approach. I thought at something like an erosion that stops when the blob size is 1 pixel, but I am having hard time at thinking at an algorithm that avoids `findContours`. Any idea?

Comment: how about the center of mass? mean of all x and all y?

Comment: @saykou That works as long as you've only got one component. Otherwise you're back to identifying the components. gentleman, perhaps iteratively flood-filling components or a full-blown connected component labeling implementation would work.

Comment: @saykou It wouldn't work, I don't have an array of connected objects, I would need either `findContours` or `connectedComponents` to generate the array of vectors of points to calculate then the center of mass for each vector. Neither routine is synthesizable into an FPGA.